# Selenium - Safari - Mac - Private Window and resizing / changing position

Tags: java, macos, selenium, safari, resize

I just started running Selenium on a Mac.  Using the Safari browser.  Language = Java.  When a script runs the browser always launches a private window.  The window opens small in the lower left corner and cannot be resized.  I have tried multiple ways of moving and resizing this window and it does not seem to work.

I know there is an existing issue with resizing / maximizing the browser in Safari and Chrome, but at least if I could have it not use a private window, it would remember the last size of the browser when I last ran Safari and Quit.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It actually looks like the window is NOT opening in Private.  It just opens in a tiny annoying window that I can't resize or move.  Maybe if I do open a private window it will open larger.  How can I do THIS?

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using to resize which is not working?